# No data was returned from ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a beginner with ASP.net so bear with me. I am trying a basic edit function for students to edit their details. This involves joining one table to another. The edit was working fine previous to the inner join, however once I added this to the select command and now I receive no data when site is rendered. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
            SelectCommand="SELECT student.Id, student.studentno, student.pword, student.fname, student.lname, student.pathway, pathway.pathwayname FROM student INNER JOIN pathway ON student.pathway = pathway.pathwayname WHERE (student.studentno = @studentno)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE student SET student.fname=@fname, student.lname=@lname WHERE student.Id=@ID">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="studentno" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="lname" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pathway" Type="int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="fname" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pword" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="studentno" QueryStringField="studentno" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="username" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <asp:ListView ID="displayedit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="Id">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <span style="">
                studentno:
                <asp:Label ID="studentnoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("studentno") %>' />
                <br />
                fname:
                <asp:TextBox ID="fnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fname") %>' />
                <br />
                lname:
                <asp:TextBox ID="lnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lname") %>' />
                <br />
                pathway:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pathway") %>' />
                <br />                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                <br /><br /></span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data was returned.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <span style="">studentno:
                <asp:TextBox ID="studentnoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("studentno") %>' />
                <br />pword:
                <asp:TextBox ID="pwordTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pword") %>' />
                <br />fname:
                <asp:TextBox ID="fnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fname") %>' />
                <br />lname:
                <asp:TextBox ID="lnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lname") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                <br /><br /></span>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="">
                studentno:
                <asp:Label ID="studentnoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("studentno") %>' />
                <br />
                pword:
                <asp:Label ID="pwordLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pword") %>' />
                <br />
                fname:
                <asp:Label ID="fnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fname") %>' />
                <br />
                lname:
                <asp:Label ID="lnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lname") %>' />
                <br />
                pathway:
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pathway") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
<br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </div>
                <div style="">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <span style="">Id:
                <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                studentno:
                <asp:Label ID="studentnoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("studentno") %>' />
                <br />
                pword:
                <asp:Label ID="pwordLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pword") %>' />
                <br />
                fname:
                <asp:Label ID="fnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fname") %>' />
                <br />
                lname:
                <asp:Label ID="lnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lname") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
<br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>



    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that student.pathway = pathway.pathwayname? Perhaps student.pathway is a Code, and pathway.pathwayname is the full string representation? One way to tell is to copy the SQL into SQL Server Management Studio and run it against your database to see if you get results.

Comment: Ahhh yes, I should have been referencing the id and not the pathway name. Thank you!